# Access entire object of model list in view with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a list in a view:

```
 @model List<LabelPrinting.Models.UserModel>
```

Is there any way to get all of the properties of a single member of the list with jQuery like this:

```
 var user = @Model[0];
```

This statement has a syntax error but when I use single quotes it does not but I do not get the user data:

```
 var user = '@Model[0]';
```

I would rather not user the JSON encode method:

```
 var users;
 users = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) }();
```

I know this works and I can get all the data for a user with:

```
 var user = users[0];
```

I know I can get some properties of the user by:

```
 var userId = '@Model[0].UserId';
```

Why can't I get the entire user?

Comment: What is wrong with `Json.Encode()`? You can use `Json.Encode(Model[0])` to assign just the first user to a javascript object

Comment: @StephenMuecke - all I get is the class from that, not the actual user data - LabelPrinting.Models.UserModel.

Comment: The full code needs to be `var user = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model[0]))');`

Comment: @StephenMuecke - yup, I just figured that out.  Thank You!

Answer (score 3):

> This statement has a syntax error

```
var user = @Model[0];
```

Because the javascript does not know the type of your class i.e. `UserModel`, as you already mentioned you have to use Json.Encode to convert c# object to json to create the javascript object by the below statement.

```
users = function () { return @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model)) }();
```

> but when I use single quotes it does not but I do not get the user data:

```
var user = '@Model[0]';
```

Because now you are **not** assigning the object of C# but a string have value `@Model[0]`. If you print Console.log(user) it will be string `@Model[0]`